# Can't call data from table using variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql

im try to get one id details from student_details table i use $_get to grab the id from url .  Example :(http://localhost/School-project/admin/edit.php?id=2014-01)
so my if id is 2014-01 and it's a primary key in database table student_table .
I don't get any error and also not data in output .So i copy all my code below  please help me out ! 
As i'm ask question second time , maybe i don't good at how put my code in below . i also attached a snap of table structure .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKgne.png)

```
<?php

session_start();

// Viewer: Can this be abstracted away to a reusable function?
if ( !isset($_SESSION['username']) ) {
    header('Location: index.php');
    die();
}

?>

<?php include '../inc/header.php';

    $id=$_GET['id'];
    var_dump($id);

    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "smart_school");

    $queryString = "SELECT * FROM student_details WHERE id =$id";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $queryString);
    mysqli_close($conn);
    var_dump($result)

 ?>

<section id="admin">    
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-12 admin-area">
                <h1>Admin Area</h1>
                <hr>

                    <div class="col-md-3" >
                        <div class="admin-menu">
                          <!-- Nav tabs -->
                          <ul class="list-group">
                            <li class="list-group-item " ><a href="admin.php">Admin Home</a></li>
                            <li class="list-group-item " ><a href="student-update.php">Student Update</a></li>      
                            <li class="list-group-item " ><a href="admin-profile.php">Profile</a></li>                     
                            <li class="list-group-item " ><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
                          </ul>                   
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="student-details">
                        <?php
                                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {



                                        ?>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="success" ><?php echo $row["fname"] ?></td>
                                            <td class="success" ><?php echo $row["lname"] ?></td>
                                            <td class="success" ><?php echo $row["id"] ?></td>
                                            <td class="success" ><?php echo $row["age"] ?></td>
                                            <td class="success" ><?php echo $row["class"] ?></td>
                                            <td class="success" ><?php echo $row["group"] ?></td>
                                            <td class="success" ><?php echo $row["section"] ?></td>
                                            <td class="success" ><?php echo $row["year"] ?></td>

                                        </tr>
                                        <?php


                                    }
                                    ?>

                        </div>


                    </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<?php include '../inc/footer.php' ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing obviously wrong with the query, except that it is wide open to injection attack. The code does not check for any errors that are produced - it assumes that all functions return true.

The various `mysqli` functions return false if they fail, and you can then handle the error and output details of the error to help you identify the problem.

The below code is an example of error checking.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "smart_school");
// check connection 
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    die("Connect failed: ".$mysqli->connect_error);
}
// define the query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM student_details WHERE id = ?";
// prepare the query
if (!$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {
    // failed to prepare query;
    die("Prepare failed: ".$stmt->error);
}
// bind the parameter
if (!$res = $stmt->bind_param('s', $_GET['id'])) {
    // failed to bind
    die("Bind failed: ".$stmt->error);
}
// execute
if (!$res = $stmt->execute()) {
    // failed to execute
    die("Execute failed: ".$stmt->error);
}
if (!$result = $stmt->get_result()) {
    // failed to get results
    die("Get results failed: ".$stmt->error);
}
```